# Removing Excel Author

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does changing the original author of an Excel file notify the original author they have been removed?

I tested this by removing myself as the author and I did not get an alert.

Comment: Is the file shared in organization?

Comment: If you save a copy as an offline file on your local machine I highly doubt any changes will be communicated or seen by anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

It’s just text data, removing it does not inform anyone.
Consider: You could enter ‘lalala’ as author, how would an Excel install on a computer on the other site of the world be able to find and contact you from that?

Note that removing the author does not remove his potential legal copyright. Excel doesn’t know about copyright.